# When should I close my Database on my Login page?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

**EDIT**

First activity opens a database: I used the code

```
LoginDbAdapter mDbHelper; // as a data member
```

called

```
// in my onCreate() of my main activity login

mDbHelper = new LoginDbAdapter(this);
```

then in my

```
public void onResume(){
    mDbHelper.open(); // opens only when the activity is resumed
    super.onResume();
}
```

then I do the same thing above in my second activity to add a user. This worked.

My issue is as follows: 
**How do i open a link to a second table in my database to access

a users information only. And where do i close it. **

**UPDATE**

an alternative way that works much better is initializing my DbAdapter in the onResume and then calling `DbAdapter.open();` only when i need access to the db and closing it right after the work is done with `DbAdapter.close();`

note: it is also important to call `startManagingCursor(cursor);` and `stopManagingCursor(cursor);`

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144328/idiom-to-close-a-cursor) may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might these helps:

find these where you getting writeable permission like these::

```
SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Now wat you need to do iz::

```
db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
db.close();//put these after inserting your database;
```

You need to go in to your DATABASEADAPTER class
then close the database connection after insertion as per above code

Comment: not quite working, should i only open my database inside the dbadapter? for example should i only be initializing the dbadapter and using the insert stuff if i already have a method that opens the database in my dbadapter?

Comment: if you have method tht opens up database connection then you should close it after insertion. Using some method which closes database connection or close it directly like these : 'db.close();'

Comment: I will be posting my full code for you to get a better idea, but now I am not even calling open on anything other than a cursor from my login page. And i am still getting the error. Maybe you can help me clean up my code. . . posting in five minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your Activity

```
mDbHelper= new DatabaseAdapter(this);
```

and in your insert method of `DatabaseAdapter` class

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

and at last in your insert method call `db.close();`

Answer (score 0):

### You need to Edit these line inside your LoginDbAdapter inside close() method;

```
public class LoginDbAdapter
 {
   // close the database
     public void close(){
     if(mDbHelper != null){
      mDbHelper.close();
       mDb.close;//insert these line ;these close sqlitedatabase;
       }

    }

   }
```

Comment: also call **close()** method after inserting data into datatabase

Comment: this helped correct the error on the adding a user, but it did not solve the new user button selected. Thanks for helping correct one of my issues.

Answer (score -1):

give the command to close inside a try{} catch{}

Comment: This is a last resort, find out what the problem is. Not by hiding it.