# ContentResolver always returns null

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the content type of a local file on my android device. My code is

```
File file = new File(uploadPath.replace("file://",""));
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
ContentResolver contentResolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
String type = contentResolver.getType(uri);
```

My upload path is `file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141016_181148.jpg`. However, I always get my `type` as null. Why is that??

Comment: Any solution to this problem? i am still getting null

Comment: In my case getType() returned null because the file extension was in upper case (.JPG) ... ContentResolver.getType() didn't like that for whatever reason ...

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with latest coding standards, there are a lot of [changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage) in terms of how the storage is managed and we access it. To answer your question, you got to replace `Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);` with below code:

Java:

```
 Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                            context,
                            context.getPackageName() + ".provider",
                            file
                        );
```

Kotlin:

```
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                                context,
                                context.packageName + ".provider",
                                file
                            )
```

Don't forget to check the official documentation on

- [FileProvider API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider)
- [FileProvider.GetUriForFile()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File))

I hope this helps!

Comment: Throws an exception for me, 'Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.test.app.provider'.  In my case the file lives in my apps sandbox, so I doubt I need to use the FileProvider API.  Uri.fromFile(file) works fine, however I cannot get the contentType.

Comment: @lostintranslation You really have to read over the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) for this to understand. Using FileProvider also requires adding code to your manifest file also.

Answer (score 3):

The content resolver will return null if the uri scheme is not content://

Comment: Can you document your answer?

Comment: Sweet, so what is the right way to get content type for a file:// scheme?

Answer (score 1):

to get the type of a file, look in there : [How to determine MIME type of file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589645/how-to-determine-mime-type-of-file-in-android)

Reasons about possible null value:

[What causes Android's ContentResolver.query() to return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080540/what-causes-androids-contentresolver-query-to-return-null)

from what i can see the uri is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin

get the mime with ContentResolver

```
var cr:ContentResolver = context.contentResolver
    var mime = cr.getType(uri)
```

the results will look like this:
mime = "image/jpeg"