# Why does ContentResolver.query return null on some phones?

Tags: android

```
ContentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID}, null, null, null)
```

This returns `null` on some phones with no exception. Why? If i do this in the `mainThread` to make it happen?

Comment: May be this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16108435/3110234

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes Android's ContentResolver.query() to return null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080540/what-causes-androids-contentresolver-query-to-return-null)

Comment: Made title grammatically correct and improved english in the rest of it.