# Show the thumbnail of a video with http

Tags: android, video

I want to show the thumbnail videos in an `ImageView`. The videos are uploaded by the users and stored on a server. At the moment I have not set up any mechanism to store and upload the videos so I'm testing this with a sample video file that is accessed using http protocol. But, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080540/what-causes-androids-contentresolver-query-to-return-null) post says that

> ContentResolver.query returns null if the uri scheme is not of the form content://

Is my approach wrong? Is it possible to use this approach with http?

This is my test code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testlayout);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/BlackBerry.3gp");
    Log.i("m",getRealPathFromURI(this, uri));
}
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null)
    {
        Log.i("m","null");
        return "";
    }
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problems with your code.

Your `getRealPathFromURI()` is broken in general on ~600 million Android devices at the present time (everything that runs Android 4.4 or higher), for any `Uri` value, let alone the one that you are trying. [A `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). Wherever you got the `Uri` from, it may not point to something from `MediaStore`. Even if it is something from the `MediaStore`, you will not get a file path from `MediaStore` via `DATA`. And even if it were possible to get a file path, you might not have access to that file (e.g., it is stored on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html)).

`MediaStore` is an index of local content. Hence, in your specific case, unless your Android device is running the Web server hosted at `download.wavetlan.com`, the content at your URL is not local, and so `MediaStore` will know nothing about it.

Please have your server generate a thumbnail, and then you can use an [image loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to get that thumbnail.

Comment: I love answers like this. Especially the last paragraph. Indeed I copy and pasted the code blindly (the main reason was I didn't know whether this approach is right at all). You answered my main question indeed.