# Why is contentResolver.query() returning null?

Tags: android, kotlin, aws-amplify

I am refactoring the AWS [S3TransferUtilitySample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample) from Java to Kotlin, and hit an exception when I try to upload an image. I traced the error to after the gallery intent returns to my app with an image URI. Within `onActivityResult`, [`getContentResolver.query(...)`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/S3TransferUtilitySample/src/com/amazonaws/demo/s3transferutility/UploadActivity.java#L564) is the problem.

- **Java** `cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);` translates in my code to
- **Kotlin** `cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)`.

The `query` argument values at this point are:

- **`uri`**: `content://media/external/images/media`
- **`projection`**: `{"_data"}`
- **`selection`**: `"_id=?"`
- **`selectionArgs`**: `{"3812"}`
- **`sortOrder`**: `null`

I looked up the documentation for [`contentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/ContentResolver.html) and I think I may be unpacking the query arguments wrong. I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108435/270847), but nothing there helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think in you image media has no image of id `3812` and  if you check all media has return to remove `projecton`, `selection`, `selectionArgs` in query only fire query with `uri`; and check result

Comment: Thanks @AshishPatidar. I think `3812` is parsed correctly from the path of the selected image. I'm not sure if I understand your second suggestion. The `query(...)` method must take each of those parameters, so I can't fire it with just `uri`. Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: `Cursor c1 = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);` this is example i have run for Contact only for URI other parameter are null.

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions error. In the Logcat, I saw

```
2019-07-30 09:32:57.566 11640-12481/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=13823, uid=10149 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:633)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:503)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:214)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:102)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

Then I saw that I had commented out the permissions code beforehand to get a better understanding of what's going on. Mission accomplished smh. I actually just deleted the commented code and wrote it from scratch to drive the lesson home.

Here's what fixed it:

- Add permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”/>`

- Check for, and grant permission to the app when the user presses the **Upload Image** button

```
    buttonUploadImage!!.setOnClickListener {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    val permissions = arrayOf(permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

                    val intent = Intent()
                    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
                    intent.type = "image/*"

                    if (checkSelfPermission(permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                                permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            // Explain why the permission is needed
                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, PERMISSION_CODE)
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Permission has already been granted
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSION_CODE)
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

**Resources**

- [Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)
- [AWS S3TransferUtilitySample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample)