# java.lang.NullPointerException: .Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, cursor, attachment

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object
>   reference

I want to attach file.

It can be any thing image,doc,pdf.

In my activity :

```
String attachmentFile;
    Uri URI = null;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 101;
    int columnIndex;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_add_notice );

        edBlock.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFolder();
            }
        }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        try {
            if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);

                 cursor.moveToFirst();
                columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                attachmentFile = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                Log.e("Attachment Path:", attachmentFile);
                URI = Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentFile);
                cursor.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d( "Exception : " , e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    public void openFolder()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
    }
```

It generate error in onActivityResult at line cursor.moveToFirst();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes Android's ContentResolver.query() to return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080540/what-causes-androids-contentresolver-query-to-return-null)

Comment: why comment this out ? `//if (cursor != null) {
                    //cursor.moveToFirst();
                //}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

try getting index before moving cursor

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            try {
                if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);

                    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToLast()
                    attachmentFile = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    Log.e("Attachment Path:", attachmentFile);
                    URI = Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentFile);
                    cursor.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d( "Exception : " , e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
```

Comment: it throws error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at line  cursor.moveToLast();

Comment: did you add the columnName parameter `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA`